# What is a quick way to run a single script to automatically install missing modules using only Perl core?

Tags: perl, dependencies

I inherited a project which is supposed to be able to be deployed to other servers. This project has a number of simple module dependencies which however might not be present on all target machines.

As such I'd like to be able to run a single command line script that checks which Perl modules are installed and tries to automatically install missing ones via CPAN.

Since this should be very basic (i.e. needing to install stuff to run the module installer would defeat the point) said script should only use Perl 5.8.8 core modules.

Does something like that exist already or would i need to write it myself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependencies+perl

Comment: If everything else fails: Cf. Module::ScanDeps or even PAR::Packer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a Bundle package is one possible [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240704/how-can-i-determine-cpan-dependencies-before-i-deploy-a-perl-project/241081#241081).

You can then look at something like `CPAN::Shell` (see [`CPAN`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN/) module) to automate the process.

/I3az/

**Update** re: brian's comment about `Task::` - Here are some pertinent links:

- [Writing a CPAN Task (using Module::Install)](http://perl.bristolbath.org/blog/lyle/2009/02/writing-a-cpan-task.html)
- ["Task:: or Bundle::"? (Perlmonks)](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=604600)

Comment: Task:: is the new Bundle:: :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Module::Install](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Install/), it will be bundled with your module/program. You can use "auto_install" command to automatically install dependencies.

Comment: Two problems with that. First off, according to Module::Corelist that's not part of 5.8.8 core. Secondly, the project itself will be deployed via pulling from github. It's not even close to being in a sane enough state to be considered for deploying by Module::Install.

I'm really only looking for a one-shot batch installer of a list of given modules.

Comment: As I said, it will be bundled. And it will be bundled automatically if you use it. But, of course, it will require some simple refactoring.