# Automatically Install Package-Based Perl Modules in Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, dependencies, package, cpan

I would like to install the Perl modules required by a specific Perl script, such as those listed by the `perl-depends` tool. However, I would like to do that in Ubuntu using the `apt-get`, meaning installing the modules through the package repository and not through CPAN.

Most similar questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019701/what-is-a-quick-way-to-run-a-single-script-to-automatically-install-missing-modul)) address ways of doing that through CPAN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Debian-Apt-PM](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Debian-Apt-PM/)

Answer (score 1):

This will list all packages having perl in them:

sudo apt-cache search perl *

then:

sudo apt-get install pkg_name_in_output