# How can I make inc::module::install suggest ubuntu packages? Should I?

Tags: perl, deployment, ubuntu, cpan, apt

I'm trying to deploy an app I wrote onto a new virtual machine and ran into some compatability issues after using cpan to install all of the dependencies I listed inside of my Makefile.pl.  In addition to that, some of the modules really just are generally better with some ubuntu package intergration(i.e getting Crypt::SSLeay to work, or some xml modules that depend on system libraries).

So my problem is both that CPAN is installing the latest version of modules when my code apparently is only working on old ones, and that it has trouble installing some of the newer ones at all.

My temporary solution is just to come up with a list of ubuntu packages and make a apt-get install line that you have to run before Makefile.PL, but this seems like a hack.

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966505/automatically-install-package-based-perl-modules-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your code work with the latest versions. Try that first. :)
2. Use a MiniCPAN, Pinto, or other module manager to freeze a repo at the versions of the modules that you need.
3. Distribute your code with the versions of the dependencies you need.